# Why am I getting OverQuotaException when trying to send an email?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a free Java application running on GAE that needs to send 3 emails per day. It used to send 2 per day and it worked fine, but when I increased it to 3 it started throwing an OverQuotaException. All 3 calls to the Mail API are executed in the same method at 00:00 hs, but I understand that you can send up to 8 emails in the same minute within the free quota.

This is the exception:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call mail.Send() required more quota than is available.
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sending the emails to multiple recipients? If so, each recipient is counted as a separate email.

Or you might be hitting the 340 KB/minute limit if your emails are long.

If your emails have several attachments, you might also be hitting the 8 attachments/minute or 10 MB attachments/minute limit.

Comment: They are sent to single recipients and have no attachments, but I didn't know about the 340 KB/minute and that may be it. Let me debug it and I will accept your answer if you were right. Thanks!